# How to ignore/continue if TD does not contain an image?

Tags: php, continue, domxpath

I need to `continue;` if `TD` does not contain an image.

I tried this:

```
if(!$image){continue;}
```

but that did not work.

```
<?php
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $html='
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <span>green</span>
                        <img src="green.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>yellow</span>
                        no image !!
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>red</span>
                        <img src="red.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>black</span>
                        <img src="black.gif" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        ';
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $query = $xpath->query('.//table/tr/td');
        for( $x=0,$results=''; $x<$query->length; $x++ )
        {
            $x1=$x+1;

            $color = $query->item($x)->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $image = $query->item($x)->getELementsByTagName('img');
            if(!$image){continue;} 
            $image = $image->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

            $results .= "color $x1 is : $color - and- image $x1 is : $image<br/>";
        }
        echo $results;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`if(!count($image)){continue;}`

But it would be much more efficient to modify your query as Gordon suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
.//table/tr/td[img]
```

or (since loadHTML adds an HTML skeleton):

```
/html/body/table/tr/td[img]
```

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/TsMVxe

Comment: @al-dr why do you need it in the loop? Why is that better to skip in the loop instead of directly fetching only those nodes that do have an img child element?

Comment: hi Gordon, because sometimes i need to make conditional,  
if (!$image){$image='default value';}

Comment: @al-dr well, you should have explained that in the question then because you only asked how to ignore/continue it and not how to set a default.

Comment: not just for set default value, it just for example .. and about your note, you are right +1 . next time i will ::